VS Code GitLens "GitHub request timed out"
I recently started to get this error when starting my VS Code from GitLens:
"GitHub request timed out."
"Source - GitLens - Git Supercharged"

VSCode version: Version: 1.94.2 (Universal)
GitLens version: v15.6.0

Does anyone know how to solve it?


Share settings please

@avifen thanks for your response, how can I see my settings in order to share them?

In the picture added, there's setting icon, pres on it and go to extension settings.
Another settings to check — on vs-code bottom left, pres on user icon and check if are connected to your GitHub account.

Name: GitLens — Git supercharged
Id: eamodio.gitlens
Description: Supercharge Git within VS Code — Visualize code authorship at a glance via Git blame annotations and CodeLens, seamlessly navigate and explore Git repositories, gain valuable insights via rich visualizations and powerful comparison commands, and so much more
Version: 15.6.2
Publisher: GitKraken
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens
